# An example a space connected but not locally connected

Tags: general-topology

The following example which is a connected space but not locally connected is from Willard, General topology.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $S_{n}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: 0\leq x\leq 1/n, nx+y=1\}$. Let $X=\{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: 0\leq y\leq 1\}\cup (\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_{n})$. It is true that $\{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: 0\leq y\leq 1\}$  is connected and every $S_{n}$ connected. And since the point $(0,1)\in S_{n}$ for each $n$. Then union of all $S_{n}$ is connected. And also $(0,1)\in \{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: 0\leq y\leq\}$, then $X$ is connected. But I could not understand why $X$ is not locally connected. It says that all of the open neighborhoods which do not contain the point $(0,1)$ of the point $(0,1/2)$, so $X$ is not locally connected.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?

Comment: There is a picture, I couldn’t understand it also @DanRust

Comment: Intuitively, a space is locally connected if at any point, you can find a small region around it which is connected. But no matter how small a neighbourhood around $(0,0.5)$ you take, it will contain some of the other 'strands', but not the join connecting them.

Comment: "all of the open neighborhoods which do not contain the point $(0,1)$ of the point $(0,1/2)$" is not a statement.

Comment: What is the statement? why are they not connected? @AnneBauval

Comment: I only complained I couldn't understand this sentence because it is not syntactically well-formed (no verb and complement). + What does "they" denote in your last comment? Do you mean "it"? (i.e. $X$) If so, I think Zoe Allen's comment answers your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Space is connected but not locally connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828532/space-is-connected-but-not-locally-connected)

Comment: why are not All of the neighbourhoods which do not contain the point 4(0,1)$ (they) of the pooint $(0,1/2)$ connected. @AnneBauval

Comment: Oh, I see. Then please edit your post to complete the incriminated meaningless sentence (also, it would be more understandable if you put "of the point $(0,1/2)$
" before "which do not contain the point $(0,1)$").

Comment: ok. thank you very much. @AnneBauval

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a neighborhood (in $X$) of the point $P:=(0,1/2)$ which does not contain the point $(0,1).$ It contains points of $X$ close to $P,$ hence at least a point of $S_n$ for some $n.$

Then, it can be partitionned into two non-empty open subsets of itself: $\{(x,y)\in V\mid nx+y<1\}$ and $\{(x,y)\in V\mid(n+1)x+y>1\}.$

Comment: I will check this, it seems a bit complicated, will try to understand. Thank you very much. @AnneBauval

Comment: I rewrote the same partition in a hopefully simpler manner.

Comment: Thank you very much @AnneBauval